# Can ellipsis occur after time phrases?

Tags: ellipsis

Can ellipsis occur after time phrases?
Is ellipsis possible in sentences like:

> 1. Recently ∅ realized that the event.... (or)
> 2. Last night ∅ was hanging out with my boyfriend when....
>
> (∅ = omitted subject)

The fact that the sentences are introduced by time phrases make it less probable, in my opinion. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, you are right that ellisis of subject "I" is less likely with a fronted component. Note, however, that such ellipsis is not strictly grammatical and is only reserved for colloquial contexts.

Comment: **Last night was hanging out with my boyfriend** leaves open the possibility that it wasn't you doing the hanging out.

Comment: I tried to clarify the context a bit. Could you verify? You can [edit] your post at any time.

Comment: recently realized is not a "time event". It is a verb with an adverb.

Answer (score 1):

> introduced by time phrases make it less probable, in my opinion. Is this right?

Yes, it makes it less probable.

However, at the same time, it wasn't probable to begin with. Such an ellipsis is not strictly grammatical, and only occurs in certain colloquial contexts, in casual spoken conversations. Many people wouldn't use this ellipsis, with or without a time phrase.

Keep in mind that one of the main definitions of "ellipsis" is literally "three dots"...   You have included both "∅" and "..." in your question which might confuse things.

Comment: +1 Looks like OP "answered" with a thank you, but it's been deleted. Sorry for the possible confusion. I added the little empty symbol, not OP, as that is how I and a few of the comments interpreted it, and which OP seems to confirm with the "thanks".